# How to get AWS subnet name from AWS CLI or EC2 metadata

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I can get to the subnet id though not the subnet name, I don't see this in the metadata either...

I need to switch based the subnet name on a script, don't want to have ids mapped to logical names...

Wondering how/if I can get the subnet name somehow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use the CLI you can use `ec2 describe-subnets`, like so:

```
aws ec2 describe-subnets --subnet-ids $SUBNET_ID --query "Subnets[*].Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value" --output text
```